# How to pass a char array in C?

Tags: c, list

I have this basic Linked List structure:

```
struct node
{
    char *name;
    float salary;
    struct node *nextNode;
};

struct list
{
    struct node *firstNode;
};
```

This is my `insert` function:

```
void insert(struct list *pList, char *newName, float newSalary)
{
    struct node *newNode;
    newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    newNode->salary = newSalary;
    newNode->name = newName;

    if (pList->firstNode == NULL)
    {
        pList->firstNode = newNode;
        newNode->nextNode = NULL;
    }

    else
    {
        struct node *pos = pList->firstNode;
        for(; pos->nextNode; pos = pos->nextNode);
        pos->nextNode = newNode;
        newNode->nextNode = NULL;
    }

}
```

This is my `main()`:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct list lst;
    struct list *plst = &lst;

    createList(plst); //initializes the list

    char name1[] = "John";
    char name2[] = "Thomas";
    char name3[] = "Albert";

    insert(plst, name1, 1000);
    insert(plst, name2, 2000);
    insert(plst, name3, 3000);
}
```

Everything works great except for the transfer of the char array. I thought the best way to pass a char array would be by passing a pointer to the first char in the char array, but I can't see what I did wrong.

Also, would it be better to first create a new `node` and then pass a pointer to this `node` to the `insert` function? It's similar, but perhaps it is more acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
newNode->name = newName;
```

This is not the right way to copy c-strings. use `strcpy` or `strncpy`:

```
strcpy(newNode->name,newName);
```

As @Pablo pointed out you didn't allocate memory for string, so first allocate and then copy:

```
newNode->name = malloc(strlen(newName)+1);
strcpy(newNode->name,newName);
```

Comment: yeah, but `newNode->name` points into the virtual Nirvana. Before using `strcpy` you would have to allocate memory:

`newNode->name = malloc(strlen(newName)+1);`
`if(newNode->name == NULL) BANG `
`strcpy(newNode->name,newName);` 

If using a BSD or POSIX system then you could use `strdup()`

Comment: But why can't I just make `char *name` point to where `char name1` points - `"John"`?

Comment: @tempy Because in C values are passed by value. After your first call to `insert` the pointer `newName` is no longer valid in `insert` and same applies for subsequent calls.

Comment: So if I would pass `newSalary` this way: `void insert(struct list *pList, float *newSalary)` /// `float sal = 1000;` `insert(plst, &sal);` that wouldn't work either?

Comment: @yes, that won't work as well, but you can pass pointer-to-pointer so as to modify/use the pointer passed. But it's unnecessary to pass `salary` that way becuase it's just a float value, so you can just pass the value. You don't need a pointer for that.

Comment: Last question (sorry): What is the reason I can't pass it the way I did (in both the char array and the float)? I learned about C Pass-By-Value and all that but I was sure that if the float, for example, is located somewhere in the memory, and I have its address, I can pass its address just like I can pass its actual value.

Comment: In the code of the question, `newNode->name = newName;` is okay, since the arrays only go out of scope when leaving `main`, @tempy, but in general, you ought to make a copy, like KingsIndian said.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine to me. But what do you mean by *works great except for the transfer of the char array*? Do you get an error, segfault, something unexpected and if so what?

Comment: Yeah, I get `warning C4047: 'function' : 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'` and `warning C4024: 'insert' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2`

Comment: strange, GNU GCC with -Wall (all warning) didn't complain at all.
From the synatx point of view it seems ok. But it would be a better idea to allocate memory for `newNode->name` and use `strcpy` on it.

Are you using a C or a C++ compiler to compile it?

Comment: C++? I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express.

Comment: I'm still having these errors (after changing the code as you and KingsIndian suggested). All I did is allocating memory for the variable `name`: `newNode->name = (char *)malloc(strlen(newName)+1);
 strcpy(newNode->name,newName);`

Comment: then use a **C** compiler for C code. Try renaming your file from `whatever.cpp` into `whatever.c`